# .Net logger that support hierarchy and thread safety

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

I have two dlls. both are using log4Net and log.

The first Dll 'A.dll' has an async function that log parallel and has a unique id for each call.
This function is using the second dll 'B.dll' which log too.

```
logger.Log("Is about to enter B function");
B.somefucntion();
```

The problem is that I have multiple logs from 'A.dll' and 'B.dll' and I can't connect between them.

I can't send the unique id of the function to 'B.dll' (this is an extenral dll that I can't modify).

I though of a solution in which in 'A.dll' opens a scope, and every log in between this scope will be added under this scope + it's message.

```
logger.Log("Is about to enter B function");
using (logger.Scope("Bla bla " + id))
{
   B.somefucntion();
}
```

Then each log occur in 'B.dll' will start with "Bla bla + {id}".
I already implemented it and it's working.

The problem with this solution is that it's not thread safe, so multiple threads can change the current scope together. Thus the scope as no meaning.

Do you know another solution, that is already implemented/ I need to implement?

Thank you very much.

Comment: @dotctor Unnecessary comment, the question was perfectly clear. But a thank you for the edit from the community, it was appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at log4net Contexts.
They allow to add and remove programmatically properties to your logs: http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/contexts.html

In particular, have a look at ThreadContext.

Context properties can be accessed by layouts to render the message.

Comment: Sometimes I have multiple theads hierarchy Is there a way to reach the father thread and store there all the properties ?

Comment: I'm sorry but AFAIK no: there is no easy way. A general approach is to use a correlation token: an ID of your request / hierarchy that let's you "correlate" log entries.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want great traceability and hierarchy, try ReflectInsight. https://insightextensions.codeplex.com